# Pycharm не находит пакет livewires

Tags: python, pycharm

Изучаю книгу Майкла Доусона, пришлось установить пакет livewires и заменить установленный, но приложение не находит ни pygame, ни пакет livewires
Уже несколько часов решаю проблему, но нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, у вас в коде неверно прописаны импорты.

Вы можете либо импортировать библиотеку целиком и обращаться к ее элементам через точку:

```py
import pygame


img = pygame.image
```

Либо импортировать из библиотеки сами элементы и обращаться к ним как обычно:

```py
from pygame import image

img = image
```

Пример очень условный, но, надеюсь, суть ясна.